# Saving a byte into a txt document using PrintWriter

Tags: java, byte, printwriter

I have a byte I want to store in a txt document so it can be used down the line w/o recreating the byte.

I can do this using plain strings, but when I try to save the byte it saves this:

```
[B@4de1eaed
```

Is there any other way I can encode the byte so I can load it back up again and it will read the byte?

Here is my code:

```
        public static byte[] tiles;
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("mytxtdocument.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("BYTE: " + mybyte);
        writer.close();
```

Comment: Show us how you declare `mybyte`.

Comment: public static byte[] mybyte;

Comment: You can achieve an order of magnitude performance improvement on this by saving your bytes using a FileOutputStream and using write(byte[]) repeated for every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save an array of bytes:

```
public static byte[] tiles;
//...
//here you add some tiles
//...
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("mytxtdocument.txt", "UTF-8");
for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        writer.println("BYTE: " + tiles[i]);
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: Testing it now :)

Comment: It works! But, due to the size of my byte, there are now 1,000,005 lines in my .txt document (not joking).

Comment: Could be even more ;)

Comment: True! I'm working on a game where you set certain tiles to certain colours. Trying to save the tiles which have colours on them and put then on each tile when you load the game back in. Have you got any suggestions around this?

Comment: You can use an enum instead of byte to represent them... imho.
Please go on and feel free to ask.

Comment: Not sure if that would work with the code I have :/ I'll try some more methods and if not I'll come back here :)

Comment: You can achieve an order of magnitude performance improvement on this by saving your bytes using a FileOutputStream and using write(byte[]) repeated for every row

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I think this is the best way to go, could you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Please ask another question, if you have one.
Enums can be used to represent colors e.g. [this way](http://grosdim.blogspot.com/2012/06/overview-of-enum-in-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, `mybyte` is probably a `byte[]`, correct? In that case, you need to write your bytes one at a time.

```
writer.print("BYTE: ");
for (int i=0;i<mybyte.length;i++) {
  writer.print("" + mybyte[i] + " ");
}
writer.println("");
```